# Indoor map navigation for Android

Tags: android, navigation, indoor-positioning-system

There is map navigation API for android?
Google maps not support indoor maps as I want.
I want API to use customizing image and paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://indoo.rs/ - it's actually meant for indoor localization, but does indoor navigation just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at Leaflet software http://leafletjs.com/index.html that have a indoor consideration.

Comment: I'm asked about indooring system, not online map

Comment: Did you check indoor.js. It can route and create custom maps.